# How to distinguish whether or not a function given undefined intentionally

Tags: javascript, typescript, undefined, arrow-functions, type-level-computation

#### The author's question

Original question: [JavaScript - Arrow functionで、あえて引数にundefinedを渡したことを識別する方法はあるのか｜teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/312342#reply-436141)

When write arrow function as `(param) => { ... }`, is there how to distinguish "calling without param" and "calling with param `undefined`"?

Of course, should not write such a function, if really want to, that must be feasible to rewrite "write with `function` and check `arguments.length`" or "write argument as `args...` and check `args.length`".

And I (the author) grasp that following ways didn't work well:

- `arguments.length` - can't take `arguments` out in arrow functions
- Setting a default argument - dare to pass `undefined`, but be applied the default argument

---

#### Editor's addition

I supposed to be able to use power of TypeScript, and first, following function had been made:

```
const foo = (x: undefined) => {
  return x
}

foo() // compile error
foo(undefined)
```

This function takes `undefined` but doesn't allow no argument. Then I tried to distinguish `undefined` and `void` in type-level, though it failed. The code I wrote:

```
const foo = (x: undefined | void, c: typeof x extends undefined ? 't' | 'a' : 'f' | 'a' = 'a')   => {
  const cond: typeof c extends 't' | 'a' ? number : string
  if(typeof cond === 'number'){
    return 1
  } else {
    return 2
  }
}

console.log(foo());
console.log(foo(undefined));
```

Why it failed is, if I think about it, it is quite obvious, `typeof x` is sum of `undefined` and `void`, so the conditional expression always returns `true`. And I somehow tried to take type information out from type-level to runtime-level, but the scheme fell through.

In addition to the author's question, I want to know whether to distinguish with or without `undefined` calling in type-level.

#### Questions

- **The author's:** How to distinguish whether or not a function given undefined intentionally (whichever JavaScript or TypeScript, except as the above)

  - *Mine*: In the problem, specially focusing features of TypeScript, type-level computation.

Comment: For typescript, you'd probably need to use a generic `<T extends undefined | void>(x: T) => {…}` not a union type for the parameter. (Although unfortunately the caller may still instantiate T with the union type).

Comment: I don't understand the distinction between "I (the author)" and "I (the editor)". I would recommend to replace the former by "the original author" or "the author of the linked teratail question" or something. Alternatively, use blockquote syntax to clarify that you are quoting someone else. I would've done that edit myself, but I'm not certain it's what you meant.

Comment: @Bergi I have edited it. Anyways, I tried a generic but it didn't work well. Type variable `T` expected to fill so not to pass argument must be not allowed.

Comment: "*How to distinguish whether or not a function given `undefined` intentionally*" - at runtime, this is not possible in arrow functions, the author seems to already have understood that. At type level, you can declare a function to take either of them but not the other (resulting in type errors), but it is not possible to declare a function that would take both and distinguish them at runtime.

Comment: As thinking expressions of types in JavaScript, it shouldn't be surprised. I want more type expressions in JavaScript.